# Find which value is shared among child records

Tags: sql

I have a database which looks something like this:

```
Parent ID | Code
1         | ABC
1         | DEF
2         | ABC
2         | GHI
```

I need a SQL query that will return the common code given two parent IDs. In this case, if I want to find the common code for parents 1 and 2, the query needs to return `ABC`. I'm guaranteed that if two parents have a common code, there will only be one.

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: It's FileMaker, which strictly speaking, isn't a SQL database, but does understand SQL (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fm13_sql_reference.pdf). I know enough SQL to be dangerous, but can't seem to figure out how to do the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping and print the code with a count > 1:

```
select code from tab
where `Parent ID` IN (1,2)
group by code
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT distinct t1.code,t1.parentid,t2.parentid from tbl t1,tbl t2
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.parentid <> t2.pparentid
```

All the codes and their parents

Comment: I don't think this will quite work. I only gave two parent ID samples, but there could be a fifth record above with a different parent ID and code `GHI`. In that case unless I'm mistaken, the above would return both `ABC` and `GHI`. I need to be able to specify which two parents I'm interested in.